# Is System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Cache equals to HttpContext.Current.Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc) who explain how to use cache items expiration to make a scheduled job for ASP.NET applications without using any scheduler or windows services.
It is really interesting for me!

In the article, the author is using `HttpContext.Current.Cache` to add an item. So when item expires in cache a treatment can be done..

But in his article he's making a 'false' request from the server to himself to have access to `HttpContext` to reach Cache and add item again when the previous expires.
I tried to use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment`to access Cache without any HttpContext (so no need to make a 'DummyRequest') and it seems working.

Is there something I don't understand or know about this cache? ***Is the `HttpContext` and the `HostingEnvironment` cache different?*** I think this is the same thing, intellisense describe the twos like the 'application cache' without differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same and both call the `HttpRuntime.Cache` - From the source code:

```
public static Cache System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Cache
{
    get
    {
        return HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }
}
```

and

```
public Cache System.Web.HttpContext.Cache
{
    get
    {
        return HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }
}
```

Also this is state on the MSDN:

**HostingEnvironment.Cache**
Gets the Cache instance for the current application.
Namespace: System.Web.Hosting
Assembly: System.Web (in system.web.dll)
ref:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.cache(VS.85).aspx

**HttpContext.Cache Property**

Gets the Cache object for the current application domain.
Namespace:  System.Web
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)
ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx

Comment: thank you. In fact, in the article, the guy is using httpcontext entry to avoid the Idle time of the web application.

Answer (score 1):

Both point to the same instance of the cache. In some cases you can't get `HttpContext.Current`. Then you can always get the cache through `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Cache` as a fallback.